# Does $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1$ imply $(x_n^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of positive reals. If $(x_n^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded, then $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq 1$. Does the converse hold?

My motivation for asking this question is to prove the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem).

Comment: Look at $x_n=n^{1/n}.$

Comment: Or $x_n = 1 + n^{-1/2}$ (use $(1 + d)^n > 1 + nd$ for any $d > 0$ and integer $n \geq 2$, a consequence of the binomial theorem sometimes called Bernoulli's inequality).

Comment: I've just realized that I don't the converse to prove the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem. I only need to show that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n < 1$ implies $(x_n^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded. And this one is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sequences with limit superior equal to 1 where $x_n^n$ is unbounded. Example: let $x_n=1+\frac12$ for the first few $n$, until $x_n^n>10$. Let the next few $x_n=1+\frac13$ until $x_n^n>100$. Let the next few $x_n=1+\frac14$ until $x_n^n>1000$. Repeat the pattern. Now $x_n$ converges to 1, so has $\limsup x_n=1$, but $x_n^n$ is unbounded.

Comment: I am sorry. When I was making the question, I erroneously wrote $=1$ instead of $\leq 1$. I have now fixed this. So now "neither is true" is false.

Comment: I see. Fixed it.

Comment: Huh, your answer gave me a useful idea. Instead of tinkering with specific numbers such as $10, 100, 1000, \dots$, you could've said "repeat $1+\frac{1}{2}$ until you have $(1+\frac{1}{2})^n > 2$, then repeat $1+\frac{1}{4}$ until you have $(1+\frac{1}{4})^n > 3$ and so on. Clearly, $x_n \to 1$ while $x_n^n$ is unbounded." I expect this will be a useful technique for constructing sequences which I will get to use in the future. So, uh, thanks.